# Require a jQuery-Plugin with Webpack

Tags: jquery-plugins, webpack, webpack-2

I want to use Webpack in order to create one single `scripts.js` file out of all needed Javascript files.

Within my `main.js` I require three modules:

```
require('jquery');
require('readmore');
require('foundation');
```

My `webpack.config.js` is this:

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: ["./js/main.js"],
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
        filename: "scripts.js"
    },
    resolve: {
        modulesDirectories: ["bower_components", "node_modules"],
        alias: {
            jquery: '../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
            readmore: '../node_modules/readmore-js/readmore.js',
            foundation: '../bower_components/foundation-sites/dist/js/foundation.js'
        }
    }
}
```

My problem: as `readmore-js` is a jQuery-Plugin it requires jQuery by itself.
I got this error after running Webpack:

```
ERROR in ./~/readmore-js/readmore.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'jquery' in '/Users/myName/www/myProject/node_modules/readmore-js'
 @ ./~/readmore-js/readmore.js 17:4-31
 @ ./js/main.js
 @ multi main
```

From my understanding the problem is that readmore also wants to load the module jQuery within the directory "nodes_modules". My first approach was to resolve this problem by adding `moduleDirectories` to the config-file, but it does still not work.
And even in this case, the plugin shouldn't load jQuery again.

Do you have any idea how I can load jQuery globally and then "tell" all modules which require jQuery by themself "look, it's there!"

As it may helps, the following is copied out of the plugin's `readmore.js`:

```
(function(factory) {
  if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    // AMD
    define(['jquery'], factory);
  } else if (typeof exports === 'object') {
    // CommonJS
    module.exports = factory(require('jquery'));
  } else {
    // Browser globals
    factory(jQuery);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [webpack.ProvidePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/provide-plugin/#use-jquery) for this:

Remove require jquery from `main.js`:

```
require('readmore');
require('foundation');
```

Configure webpack.ProvidePlugin inside `webpack.config.js`:

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: ["./js/main.js"],
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
        filename: "scripts.js"
    },
    resolve: {
        modulesDirectories: ["bower_components", "node_modules"],
        alias: {
            readmore: '../node_modules/readmore-js/readmore.js',
            foundation: '../bower_components/foundation-sites/dist/js/foundation.js'
        }
    },
    plugins: [
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: 'jquery',
        jQuery: 'jquery'
      }),
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thx for your answer, the webpack command works!
But I got a problem with running the scripts.js as I can't access the plugin anymore: 

```Uncaught TypeError: $(...).readmore is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> [...] ``` 
I think I still have a problem with the global varibles?

Comment: I got a similar issue. It's quite a mystery how some plugins are loaded and others are not. I have an existing project, but cannot seam to figure out why some work and other don't.